# Maven dependency of other modules not resolved in Android application

Tags: android, maven, dependencies

While working in a multi-module project, I wanted to use classes from other modules in my Android Application. So, I added dependency of the module and tried to build Android App with maven. I get an exception:

> 

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
[INFO] Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
```

When I added scope provided to dependency of that module, build was successful but import of class of that module was not getting resolved.

I also added dependency of gson in maven. The build was successful but

> import com.google.gson.Gson;

was not getting resolved. 
Can anyone help here why imports are not getting resolved in my android app?

Comment: `bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`  What version of java are you using?  Try using `Java 7`

Comment: The installed Java version is "1.8.0_45".

Comment: Can you try using `Java 7`?

Comment: With Java 7, I am still getting exception while building Android App. Copying the initial part of the Error message:  Failed to execute goal com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.1.1:dex (default-dex) on project Android-app: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: ............   (its a long error message).